# Inner loop inside a for loop is not working

Tags: bash, git, loops, shell

I have 2 for loops 1 is to clone several git repos one after the other and the 2nd loop is to count number of subdirectories inside each repo folders (tier1, tier2, tier3).

**CODE1:**

```
    #!/bin/bash

URL="https://git.com/scm/bnktst/allstars-autopilot-testcases.git https://git.com/scm/bnktst/anacredit-autopilot-testcases.git"

for URL in $URL
do
    git clone --depth=1 $URL
done
```

**CODE 2:**

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for topdir in tier[1-3]
do
  if [[ -d $topdir ]]
  then
   a=("$topdir"/*/)  
    echo "Number of subdirectories below $topdir is ${#a[@]}"
  fi
done
```

What I wanted to do is to merge both the codes, i did the following but only the first code is working. That is, it is only counting repos but not counting the directories.

**Merged code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="https://bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/allstars-autopilot-testcases.git https://bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/anacredit-autopilot-testcases.git"

for URL in $URL
do
    git clone --depth=1 $URL
    shopt -s nullglob
    for topdir in tier[1-3]
    do
        if [[ -d $topdir ]]
        then
         a=("$topdir"/*/)  
          echo "Number of subdirectories below $topdir is ${#a[@]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

I wanted to make the merged code work.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `cd` into the cloned repositories?

Comment: I'm not that much a git specialist, but in your `git clone`, you only provide a _repository_, but not a directory to clone into. AFIK, git then clones into `$PWD`. This would mean that it just stacks on each iteration one repo on top of the previous one. For debugging, I would do a `ls` after the `git clone`.

Comment: BTW, I've added a _bash_ tag, since you are searching specifically for a bash solution (and not a plain (POSIX-)shell script).